# Processing a list of JSON file URLs with Node.js and BASH

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, bash

I have a text file with a long list of 450 urls that each link to a separate JSON file. I'm trying to use JavaScript with Node.js to read the file and parse the necessary information from the JSON file (In this case, the name and number of appearances they have). I'm using a BASH script to run this file on all the urls in the my text file urls.txt, but currently, it will only run on the very first url, then the JSON information doesn't get parsed for the rest of the urls. Here is my parser.js

```
var request = require("request");
var fs = require("fs");

var url = process.argv[2];
//console.log(url);

request(url, function (error, response, body) {

if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
    //console.log(body) // Print the json response
    var jsonObj = JSON.parse(body.toString()); 
    console.log(jsonObj["results"][0]["name"] + ", " + jsonObj["results"][0]["num_results"]);
}
})
```

and here is my bash script

```
while read line; do
    ./node-v4.4.1-linux-x64/bin/node parser.js $line
done < urls.txt
```

calling the bash script results in the output:

```
Robert B. Aderholt, 20
```

Note that when console.log(url) in parser.js is uncommented, the output looks like this:

```
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/A000055/floor_appearances.json?committees&api-key=
Robert B. Aderholt, 20
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/A000210/floor_appearances.json?committees&api-key=
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/A000361/floor_appearances.json?committees&api-key=
http://api.nytimes.com/svc/politics/v3/us/legislative/congress/members/A000367/floor_appearances.json?committees&api-key=
```

and continues with the 450 urls from urls.txt after that. Thank you in advance for anyone who can help!

-Paco

Comment: 2 things: 1. You're using bad api-keys in the other calls. 2: You should probably delete your api-key from a public forum.

Comment: Your if loop is wrong, and it will only run once. Update your code to loop through your Jsonobject.

Comment: Thanks @Wainage that was it! I hadn't realized that excel had automatically incremented the numbers when I was creating the urls.

Comment: @PacoAvila if the comment helped you, it's probably best to delete your question